# how do i design a tornado static handler to serve lots of f video files using the same statichandler?

Tags: python, url, python-2.7, tornado

I have about 5 categories of video's and each  category has several hour-long session of video  files, i'd like to serve all these to the end user using tornado to  give them the video that they request, what is the best way to get this done? (i'd like an automated way of generating the urls since the server could just watch some directory where the video's are placed/added and automatically add the video to the corresponding category menu/ create new category, this also means im avoiding a handler for each category). Is what im thinking possible?

```
class VideoHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("relevant-video") # serve correct video maybe suing the incoming url?

settings = {'static_path': os.path.join(PATH, 'static')}

handlers = [(r'/videos', VideoHandler),
            (r'/favicon.ico', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': favicon_path})]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run periodically a task using [`tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback) to create dictionary mapping videos to categories:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web

from tornado.options import define, options
define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)

videos = {}

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('index.html', my_videos=videos)

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", MainHandler),
        ]
        settings = dict(
            template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
            static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
            debug=True,
        )
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)

    def update_categories(self): 
        videos.clear()
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(self.settings['static_path'] + '/videos/'):
            category_name = os.path.basename(path)
            videos[category_name] = []
            for name in files:
                videos[category_name].append(name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = Application()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(app.update_categories, 1000).start() # run every second
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I use subdirectory name as a category name. Project tree:

```
 $ tree 
 .
 ├── static
 │   └── videos
 │       ├── cat1
 │       │   ├── vid1.avi
 │       │   └── vid2.avi
 │       ├── cat2
 │       │   ├── vid3.avi
 │       └── Empty category
 ├── templates
 │   ├── index.html
 └── test.py
```

I'm using this template:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for category in my_videos %}
        <h1>{{category}}</h1>
        {% for video in my_videos[category] %}
            <p>{{video}} -> {{static_url("videos/")}}{{category}}/{{video}}</p>
        {% end %}
    {% end %}
</body>
</html>
```

It prints all videos. You can also select one video from dictionary in your handler and process it.

This approach is a bit heavy because file system is traversed regularly. It's better to notify application when new content is added instead.